# how to access json data in dom using vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

please how can i access json in dom using vue js

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      responseObject: ""
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/blogs");
      console.log(response);
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is my template to display the data and it doesn't show anything

```
  <div>
    {{responseObject}}
  </div>
```

this is my json data i want to display

```
{
"status": true,
"responseObject": {
        "resource": "services",
        "status": "success",
        "data": [
            {
                "service_id": "0001",
                "service_name": "Buy Airtime",
                "service_type": "airtime"
            },
]}}
```

please how can i display the json data in my dom

Comment: you're not assigning the axios response to the correct variable...  try `this.responseObject = await axios.get(...)`

Comment: @yoduh please how can i loop it this doesn't display the data <div
        v-for="service in responseObject"
        :key="service._id"
      >
        <h2>{{ service.service_name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ service.service_type }}</p>
      </div>

Comment: it's likely that the `service` object is not what you think it is.  maybe try just start with displaying `{{ service }}` and see what is displayed.  the way you're using  `responseObject` I would expect it to be an array of objects and each object has root properties like `_id`, `service_name`, etc.  I'm guessing that's not true though.

Comment: What does `console.log(respose)` output? If it's something like `response.data.responseObject` then you'll need to assign that to `this.responseObject`. Another issue could be the link to `http://localhost:4000/api/blogs` is that endpoint the JSON data? Can that be checked by visiting it in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by assigning the response into your data object property.

Live Demo (descriptive comments has been added into the below code snippet) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    responseObject: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    // Just for a demo purpose I am using mock response, You can replace it with an API call.
    const response = {
      "status": true,
      "responseObject": {
        "resource": "services",
        "status": "success",
        "data": [{
          "service_id": "0001",
          "service_name": "Buy Airtime",
          "service_type": "airtime"
        }]
      }
    };
    
    // Now you can assign the required object from the response into the 'responseObject' data property.
    this.responseObject = response.responseObject.data;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="service in responseObject" :key="service.service_id">
    <h2>{{ service.service_name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ service.service_type }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```