# how to loop in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

this is my script

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      responseObject: {}
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/blogs");
    this.responseObject = response.data;
    } catch (e) { 
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

this is my responseObject json

```
 responseObject: {
        resource: "services",
        status: "success",
        data: [
          {
            service_id: "0001",
            service_name: "Buy Airtime",
            service_type: "airtime",
          },
 {
            service_id: "0002",
            service_name: "Buy Data",
            service_type: "Data",
          },
        ],
      },
```

this is my template i get the whole json using {{service}}

```
  <ul>
      <li v-for="service in  responseObject" :key="service.service_id">
        {{ service }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

please how can i loop through the data and get either of them

```
service_name: "Buy Airtime",
service_type: "airtime",
```

i've tried

```
{{servive.service_name}}
```

but it doesn't return anything

Comment: you try `{{servive['data']['service_name']}}`

Comment: @paransaik it doesn't display anything

Comment: `{{servive.service_name}}` typo?
it should be `{{service.service_name}}`

Comment: @xander I added an answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923978/how-to-access-json-data-in-dom-using-vue-js/75936543#75936543

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to repeat the data only.

```js
    <ul>
      <li v-for="service in responseObject.data" :key="service.service_id">
        {{ service.service_name }} :: {{ service.service_type }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Be careful of typos `servive`

Comment: still doesn't loop the data

Comment: Tell me the output value of "response.data"

Comment: doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="service in responseObject.data">
        {{ service.service_name }}
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- OR -->
<ol>
    <li v-for="service in responseObject.data">
        {{ service.service_type }}
    </li>
</ol>
```

Also, I don't know why you are still unable to get the data. I already get it here.

[image]

Comment: using v-for twice doesn't work

Comment: if i do {{service}} i get the json

Comment: What is the output? Can you show me? It look like this ```services,success,[ { "service_id": "0001", "service_name": "Buy Airtime", "service_type": "airtime" }, { "service_id": "0002", "service_name": "Buy Data", "service_type": "Data" } ]```

Comment: thats the response

Comment: Then you should only do this. ```{{ service.service_name }}``` or try to follow my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the child "data" array by adding dot notation to your v-for statement ("responseObject.data")-

```
    <ul>
      <li v-for="service in  responseObject.data"    :key="service.service_id">
        {{ service.service_name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/bsod_/pen/wvYwBrj